Is there a group algebra that has more relations than the group?
My notes write the relations of $\mathbb{k} S_n$ to be
\begin{gather}
s_i s_{i + 1} s_i = s_{i + 1} s_i s_{i + 1}, \quad i = 1, \dots, n - 2 \\
s_i s_j = s_j s_i, \quad \text{if } |i - j| > 1 \\
s_i^2 = 1, \quad i = 1, \dots, n - 1
\end{gather}
which makes perfect sense to me. However, it is followed by the remark that it is not a priori clear that there are no additional relations among that hold in $\mathbb{k} S_n$ via some linear combination of products. However, this confused me. Surely by the definition of a group algebra if there was some relation of linear combinations of products, say
$$\sum a_i p_i = 0$$
where I'm using $p_i$ as a placeholder for a general product, you could group them into
$$\sum_{s \in S_n} \left(\sum_{p_i = s} a_i \right) s = 0$$
and by linear independence $\left(\sum_{p_i = s} a_i \right) = 0$ so that we don't get any new relations? As any potential "new relation" is just given by arithmetic in $\mathbb{k}$. I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this, but the notes seem to make it appear that this is not this clear or that there are counterexamples, so I'm a bit confused. Maybe I'm thinking about relations wrong though, I've never really studied group presentations.

The universal property of the group algebra implies immediately that if a group has generators and relations in the category of groups, its group algebra is defined by the same generators and relations in the category of algebras, plus the relations that the generators are units - formally we the need to add their inverses to the generators.
Formally: Say $G = \langle X \mid R\rangle$, meaning
$\hom(G,H) \cong \{f : X \to |H| : f \text{ satisfies the relations in } R\}$
for every group $H$, then for algebras $A$ we get
$\hom(k[G],A) \cong \hom(G,A^{\times}) \cong \{f : X \to |A^{\times}| : f \text{ satisfies the relations in } R\}$
$=\{f : X \sqcup X' \to |A| : f|_X \text{ satisfies the relations in } R, ~ f(x') \text{ is inverse to } f(x)\}$
(where $X'$ is a copy of $X$) and hence
$k[G] = \langle X \sqcup X' \mid R,~ x x' = x' x = 1\rangle$
in the category of algebras.
Simplest example: if $G$ is the free group on one generator $x$, then $k[G]$ is the free algebra on  generators $x,x'$ subject to the relation $x x' = x' x = 1$. (And this algebra cannot be generated by a single element, let alone with zero relations. So, formally, this is a group algebra with more relations as the group, but not "really".)
When the relations of the group already imply that each generator is invertible and the relations don't mentions the inverses explicitly, for example as $x^2 = 1$ in the example of the symmetric group, we can simplify the presentation to
$k[G] = \langle X \mid R \rangle.$
This is because of the corresponding result for monoids given by generators and relations.

Perfect, thanks!
